What is the meaning of "desires" in "who desires all people to be saved", 1 Timothy 2:4?
1 Timothy 2:3-4  NKJV

"For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, 4 who desires all men  to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth."  [My emphasis].

Here "desires" is "thelei" from "thelo".
Matthew 1:19

"Then Joseph her husband, being a just man, and not wanting to make her a public example, was minded to put her away secretly."

Here "wanting" is  "thelon" from "thelo".
Joseph's not wanting to make  Mary  a public example, is not the same as his being minded/eboulethe to act upon that desire. Wanting and being resolved to act on that desire are different in Matthew 1:19.
What is the meaning of "thelei" in 1 Timothy 2:4?

Have you consulted a standard lexicon such as https://biblehub.com/greek/2309.htm  If so, why is this not edequate?

@Dottard  Thayer says thelei in 1 Tim 2:4  "will be ranged now on one side now on the other". Yet some seem  sure that the meaning is obvious, so I would be glad to see if there are further facets to this or is it actually impossible to tie down.

The OP notes, “Joseph's not wanting to make Mary a public example, is not the same as his being minded/eboulethe to act upon that desire. Wanting and being resolved to act on that desire are different in Matthew 1:19.” I agree, the use of two different verbs helps to distinguish between two types of volitional actions.
The relevant terms in Mt 1:19 are thelō (θέλω G2309) and boulomai (βούλομαι  G1014). While both words translate into English as “to will,” they are not related etymologically. The presumed root of thelō is the verb haireō, meaning to take, to choose, to prefer. On the other hand, boulomai is the root of boulē and boulēma, nouns that mean counsel, purpose, will, or plan. Underlying thelō is thus the concept of choice; proceeding from boulomai is the notion of counsel or purpose.
Citing Mt 1:19 as an example, Thayer’s makes the following distinction between the two terms:

As respects the distinction between βούλομαι and θέλω, the former
seems to designate the will which follows deliberation, the latter the
will which proceeds from inclination.

The way thelō and boulomai are used in Mt 1:19 implies that Joseph’s will/thelō “not to make her a public example” is the reason behind his will/boulomai “to put her away secretly.” Here, thelō serves as the impetus for boulomai. The first denotes a natural inclination. The second connotes a deliberative process that is directed toward some purpose or goal.
Matthew 1:19 NKJV (superscript added)

Then Joseph her husband, being a just man, not wantingG2309
to make her a public example, was mindedG1014 to put her
away secretly

The OP asks, “What is the meaning of ‘desires’ in ‘who desires all people to be saved', 1 Timothy 2:4?”
Per the above discussion, the use of thelō in 1 Tim 2:3-4 signifies God’s desire/preference/inclination that all men be saved.
1 Timothy 2:3-4

For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, who
desiresG2309 all men to be saved and to come to the
knowledge of the truth

Barnes Commentary  on 1 Timothy 2:4

Who will have all men to be saved - That is, it is in accordance with
his nature, his feelings, his desires. The word "will" cannot be taken
here in the absolute sense, denoting a decree like that by which he
willed the creation of the world, for then it would certainly be done.
But the word is often used to denote a desire, wish, or what is in
accordance with the nature of anyone.

In my opinion, 1 Tim 2:3-4 references the overarching desire that is the impetus for God’s plan of salvation (cf. 2 Pet 3:9, Jn 3:17). But more than just a reflection of God’s feelings or His nature, it is expressly born out of God’s love for the world.
John 3:17

For God so loved the world, that He gave His only Son, so that
everyone who believes in Him will not perish, but have eternal life.


The RSV and NASB also say “desires”, but other translations use other words. The K.J.V. has “who will have”, Young’s Literal has, “who doth will”, the Englishman’s Greek New Testament has, “wishes to be saved”. It is not surprising that there are different renderings, for Young lists all the various translations of thelo in the K.J.V. as:
“be desirous, be disposed, be forward (M. be willing), be so, be willing, desire, had rather, intend, list, love, mean, will, will have, would, would have”
In Matthew 1:19, eboulethe is given in the Englishman’s Greek N.T. as ‘purposed’, and thelei / thelemon as [not] ‘willing’.
This seems to demonstrate that there is leeway to chose from a variety of English words, therefore getting to grips with ‘desires’ or ‘wills’ in 1 Timothy 2:4 could be like trying to nail jelly to a wall. So, what is the meaning? I consulted a commentary on the first letter to Timothy and noted the context for 2:4:

“The apostle’s concern is for peace, that the truth might prosper in
all the earth and among all mankind, being heard abroad throughout all
nations to the gathering in of God’s elect.
Therefore Paul exhorts that supplications, prayers, intercessions, and
giving of thanks be made for men of all nations to the ends of the
earth, with their kings and authorities, so that the saints called out
of distant kingdoms and far-flung dominions might lead a quiet and
peaceable life in all godliness and honesty.
This is acceptable to God our Saviour, and may therefore be the
subject of prayer in the assurance that it is his will, for, far from
being the God of the Jews only, he is the God of the Gentiles also,
even to the ends of all the earth.
God would have all men to be saved; that is, men not of one nation
only, but of all nations also upon the face of the earth, wherever
kings reign, or authorities exercise dominion. No less is in the mind
of God our Saviour, to redeem a great multitude out of every kindred,
and tongue, and people, and nation, from the four corners of the
earth, to the world’s ends.
He whose prayer and perception falls short of this, falls indeed. It
is to disobey the apostolic vision and exhortation of these verses,
which Timothy is to apply and require in the prayers of all saints.”
First Timothy, John Metcalfe, p.p14-15, 1995
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Metcalfe gives his own preferred translation as, “That we may lead a stable and peaceable life in all reverence and gravity. For this good and acceptable before God our Saviour, who wills all men to be saved and to come to an awareness of truth.”
Context opens up the meaning a little, it would seem, for God requires us to pray for peace in the nations to prevail so that the gospel of Jesus Christ will the better be spread all over the earth for all men to hear. The current global situation with wars and rising lawlessness surely calls us to more earnest prayer as we appreciate what God’s will – what God’s desire – is regarding declaring the gospel?

+1. ESV has 1 Tim 2:4 desires/thelei and 1 Tim 2:8 desire/boulomai. Would this change from thelei to boulomai betoken some contrast in the mind of the writer and a clue as to how thelei is being used here?

@C.Stroud  All I can comment is that, when I write, I have an aversion to repeating words in the same paragraph. But that's just me, and I do not scribe under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit! Paul did, and there is a breath-taking precision in the nuances found in Spirit-breathed letters.  (Did you see what I just did there?!) I am simply unable to say anything about the interesting question you ask.
